# How to explain packet loss inside VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I run an OpenVPN server (2.3.4) on Debian Jessie on UDP (port 1194) with TAP. The link to the Internet is 100Mbit/s (symetric).

Client runs TunnelBlick (3.7.0 with OpenVPN 2.3.14) on a MacBookPro 2015 behind a residential cable modem with 100Mbit/s down and 5Mbit/s up.

I constantly monitor packet loss both inside and outside VPN between the server and the client using Smokeping. Here are two graphs:

Outside the VPN: 0.05% packet loss ([Smokeping graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCpGY.png))

Inside the VPN : 5.26% packet loss ([Smokeping graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6KMA.png))

Smokeping runs on the VPN server and is configured to probe the public IP (outside the VPN graph) and the VPN's internal IP (inside the VPN graph).

**What could explain this difference?**

Some more details:

- CPU on the client is always lower than 50% and way lower than that on the server
- Bandwidth usage on the server is generally between 10% and 30%
- Server has 10-20 simultaneous clients connected, mostly Linux boxes, and I only observe this problem on two clients running macOS Sierra
- Sometimes, when TunnelBlick is restarted on the client, packet loss inside the VPN matches what I see outside the VPN (~0%), but sometimes it is persistent across TunnelBlick restarts

Are there any obvious things you would test on this setup?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is not the problem specific to OpenVPN server or client, but rather to MacOS Sierra. Googling "mac os sierra packet loss" gives a link dated Oct 13, 2016 named [Connection drops in macOS Sierra](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7706966?start=0&tstart=0). In your case with OpenVPN *off* not only the packets are lost, but also some packets have much longer Round Trip Time. Not 100% sure about this, but my guess would be that when you have OpenVPN *on*, if a later created packet arrived earlier than the earlier created packet, OpenVPN just decides that the earlier packet is lost without further waiting. Than is why with OpenVPN *on* the loss rate becomes higher. Or may be when ping is done inside OpenVPN encapsulation, the packets are bigger in size and become more sensitive to a bad connection. Try using

```
proto tcp-server
```

on the server side and

```
proto tcp-client
```

on the client side and see if the loss rate *with* OpenVPN becomes comparable to the loss rate *without* OpenVPN.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you suggest running the OpenVPN tunnel over TCP rather than UDP. I thought about this too but was reluctant due to the [TCP-overt-TCP meltdown issue](http://sites.inka.de/bigred/devel/tcp-tcp.html). I will give it a try anyway!

Comment: I would give it a try in order to see if this will reduce the packet loss rate. But you are right, tcp-over-tcp does have issues, including slower connection. So it depends on what you're using your openvpn tunnel for. If speed is more important, like in VoIP, I would continue using upd.